# Getting Text of an HTML Page in PHP

Tags: php, html

I was perusing some topics and started thinking about a way to get the text from an external page such as Google or Yahoo, then parsing it and getting the content(/text) of the first, say,  tagset. I couldn't think of a way so I figured I'd ask here.

Got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into Curl.

Here's a quick rundown: http://blog.unitedheroes.net/curl/

Comment: or file_get_contents() as well if no 'fancy' http options need to be specified.

Comment: @MarcB: even 'fancy' options are possible since PHP 5, through [stream contexts](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the library Snoopy

http://snoopy.sourceforge.net/